# How to define AngularJS Helpers that reuse injectors from their context?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

How do I define a function that has access to all the injected arguments of the controller/directive/service, without passing them explicitly?

```
myShortHand = function(scope, http, element, url) {
    http.get(url).success(function (data) {
        element.html(data);
    });
}

function MyCtrl($scope, $http, $element) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.click = function() { myShortHand($scope, $http, $element, url); }
}
```

This is just a simplified example, and shows the amount of boilerplate code. My shorthand actually takes 4 `$` arguments and it kind of defeats the purpose of a shorthand! Note that I can't really use a service: `$http` could be injected in a service, but `$scope` and `$element` need to use the same injector as `MyCtrl`. Is there a way to define controller methods (perhaps in the prototype) that can use dependency injection in their argument list and use the same injector as the instance they are called on?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question where the `myShortHand` function is defined but if it happens to be defined within a directive's linking function you could simply relay on the closure scope. In this case you don't need to pass arguments available in a closure.

Next, what you could do is to inject `$injector` into your directive and pass it in into the helper function as the only argument beside `$element` and `$scope`. Then, in your helper function you can retrieve any service by calling `$injector.get` method. For example, to get access to the `$http` service you could write:

```
myShortHand = function(scope, element, url, $injector) {
    $injector.get('$http').get(url).success(function (data) {
        element.html(data);
    });
}
```

This technique would work if your helper can't relay on the closure scope and needs access to several services.

Having said all the above I would re-consider code split in your helpers. Usually functions that need many arguments are not well-focused and got many side effects (or are doing too much).

Comment: 1. Obviously using closures would be simple, but this helper function must be shared among controllers (imagine doing `ngController.prototype.myHelper = ...`) 2. This doesn't seem to work: this `$injector` you get from the controller injector does not seem to be the controller injector itself: `$injector.get('$http')` works, but `$injector.get('$scope')` does not, when it should be that `$scope == $injector.get('$scope')`

Comment: @BruceBerry It won't work for $scope, as the $scope is injected in the $controller service. So no hope here.